# Sums and mathematical induction

Tags: inequality, induction

I need help with this competitive problem, the only hint I have in the book is that the problem can be solved with mathematical induction:

You have  sums of natural numbers $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k = y_1 + y_2 + \dots + y_l < k \cdot l$. Prove that you can "delete" some numbers (at least 2 but not all) so equality will stay. E.g. $1+1+2 = 1+1+2 < 9$ we can delete two 2s and we will have $1+1=1+1$.

I tried induction by $k$ and $l$ and also by $k\cdot l$ but didn't get anything.

Comment: Maybe, double induction does the job : Start with $k=1$ and show the claim for all $l$ by induction over $l$. Then, try the step from $k$ to $k+1$

Comment: @Peter Already tried but haven't succeeded

Comment: Your example is too simple.

Comment: @TutanKamon: if you tried it, that should be mentioned in the question.

Comment: @robjohn I tried to t it without induction, by contradiction but don't get anything useful. Can you give me some hint how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First note that $k\ge2$ and $l\ge2$.  Proceed by induction on $k+l$.

If $k+l=4$ then the sets are both $\{1,1\}$ or both $\{1,2\}$ and the result is obvious.

Without loss of generality we can suppose that $x_1 \le x_2  \le\dots \le x_k$ and $ y_1 \le y_2 \le \dots \le y_l $.If $x_k=y_l$ then we are finished. So we can suppose $x_k>y_l$. Deleting $y_l$ and replacing $x_k$ by $x_k-y_l$ keeps the two sums equal and (since we have removed the largest $y_i$) this sum is less than $k(l-1)$.

Then, by the inductive hypothesis two proper subsets of the $x_i$ and of the $y_i$ now have equal sums. If $x_k-y_l$ is not included in this sum then these subsets are subsets of the original sets and we are finished. If $x_k-y_l$ is included in this sum then replace it by $x_k$ and re-introduce $y_l$ to obtain proper subsets for the original sets of numbers.

Comment: I think idea is good, I didn't tried that so far. But I don't understand how is this a complete solution. I'm totally OK with beginning (1st and 2nd paragraph) and first part of 3rd. I have some questions:
1) What is induction step here? 
2) When you delete $y_l$ in 3rd paragraph I don't get how you know new sums will be less then $k(l-1)$?

Comment: (1)The induction step occurs when we consider the two sets with $y_l$ removed and where $k+l$ is therefore reduced by $1$. (2) If you suppose the $y_i$ now add up to at least $k(l-1)$ then their average is at least $k$. But then $y_l$ is at least $k$ and so the sum is less than $lk-k$, as required,

Comment: (1) For regressive induction you must have another one step e.g. from $k+l$ to $2(k+l)$ or something like that. (2) Mega cool, now clear :)

Comment: When you say that the new sum is less than $k(l-1)$ it seems you are saying $y_l\geq k$  Why is this true?

Comment: @saulspatz. If the sum of $y_i$ up to $i=l-1$ is greater than or equal to $k(l-1)$ then the average of these $y_i$ is at least $k$. Therefore (in this case) $y_l\ge k$

Comment: Thank you.  I was trying to do this last night, using essentially the same method you used, and I couldn't get past this point.  I feel so stupid.

Comment: At this point $y_l$ has been deleted. There are only $l-1$ f the $y_i$.